# PySpark - how to join two large RDD by key in a stable and reasonably fast way

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am running a **pyspark** application, and keep getting error: Container killed by YARN for exceeding memory limits. 5.1 GB of 5 GB physical memory used.

There are two dataset in hdfs, 
dataset A looks like this:

```py
a0,{"count":0, "ip":"0.0.0.0"}
a1,{"count":1, "ip":"0.0.0.0"}
a1,{"count":1, "ip":"0.0.0.1"}
a2,{"count":2, "ip":"0.0.0.0"}
a3,{"count":3, "ip":"0.0.0.0"}
...
```

dataset B looks like this:

```py
a0,{"count":0, "ip":"0.0.0.0"}
a1,{"count":1, "ip":"0.0.0.0"}
...
```

they are both key, value format sequenceFile, and I want to join A with B by key, so that I can get result like:

```py
a0,{"count":0, "ip":"0.0.0.0"}
a1,{"count":1, "ip":"0.0.0.0"}
a1,{"count":1, "ip":"0.0.0.1"}
```

and save the result to a readable format file like textfile or json or csv.

First I use cogroup:

```py
rddresult = rddA.cogroup(rddB).filter(lambda x: x[1][0] and x[1][1])
```

and I also use join:

```py
rddresult = rddA.join(rddB)
```

but both runs into memory error.
Then I think, could it be something to do with groupByKey? Since both of them use groupByKey underlying.
So I change my code like followed:

```py
def mergeSeq(a, b):
    ta = type(a)
    tb = type(b)
    if ta == list:
        res = a
    else:
        res = [a]
    if tb == list:
        res.extend(b)
    else:
        res.append(b)
    return res
def filterSeq(li):
    # filtering rows that have no value from rddB
    if type(li) != list:
        return False
    if len(li) <= 1:
        return False
    elif install_pair_flag in li: # install_pair_flag comes from rddB
        return True
    else:
        return False
rddresult = rddA.union(rddB).reduceByKey(mergeSeq).filter(filterSeq) 
# repartition seems to solve memory error but dramatically slow down the speed
# rddresult = rddA.union(rddB).reduceByKey(mergeSeq).filter(filterSeq).repartition(numPartitions=9092)
```

and again, memory error.

I do adjust my spark config by instructions from this [article](https://gsamaras.wordpress.com/code/memoryoverhead-issue-in-spark/),

```
spark-submit --master yarn-cluster --name yy-adtracking --conf spark.akka.frameSize=2000 --conf spark.yarn.maxAppAttempts=1 --conf spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead=12000  --num-executors 24 --driver-memory 4g --executor-memory 2g --executor-cores 1 runjob.py
```

but it didn't help.

Finally, I convert rdd to dataframe:

```py
sqlctx = SQLContext(SC)
dfA = sqlctx.createDataFrame(rddA, ["k", "v0"])
dfB = sqlctx.createDataFrame(rddB, ["k", "v1"])
dfresult = dfA.join(dfB, on="k", how="inner")
dfresult.write.json(path, "overwrite")
```

well, it didn't report memory error, and also faster.
But when it came to write json to disk, it became very slow, almost four time than computing.

So here come my question: 
is there a much more stable and reasonable fast solution to finish my task? or should I just stick to my current method, use repartition or dataframe?

Comment: There are multiple things that you need to consider when you try to join 2 Datasets.
How is the data distribution of the keys? Is it evenly distributed or is it skewed?
Can you do a Shuffle Hash join in your case?

Comment: @AkhilanandBenkalVenkanna Most of key appear just once in data so they are evenly distributed and each key is a 32bytes md5 signature. Isn't shuffle hash join the default spark join? If that case, then no, I can't do join, it would report memory error like cogroup did.